Why is pull-down resistor on low-pulse triggered relay input not working?
I have a low-pulse triggered latching relay board (datasheet for individual relays, link to board). Whenever I plug-in, or un-plug my Arduino Nano's USB cable the relay changes state (sometimes multiple state changes occur from a single un/plug event). I believe this is due to the floating voltage when the pins are configured as inputs briefly during initialisation. However, I have added a 10k pull-down resistor on the relay input and I am still having the same issues.
Here's a picture of my set up. What am I doing wrong here? I basically just want the relay to stay in the same state I set it to.


Tip: Use the editor toolbar CircuitLab button to draw your schematic and use the Save and Insert button to insert a PNG of the schematic into the post along with an edit link. There's no need for a CircuitLab account. No screengrab. No grid. It also means that others can copy and paste your schematic for further editing.
Double-click to edit component properties. 'H' and 'V' to flip. 'R' to rotate. 'N' for a node or external connection.

If your relay is triggered by a low pulse, then you surely need a pull-up resistor, not a pull-down .... ?

@brhans If I pull the voltage on the input up, won't it always trigger whenever the arduino is powered off as it goes from 5v to 0v? If I pull it low, it should stay at 0v unless the GPIO triggers, right?
